# CRC 16 calculation using python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, serial-communication, crc16

I have an incoming packet that reads 7E0003000204009b387E from a serial port.

start and end flag is 7E, FCS/CRC is 9b38 and the data is 00030002000400. The FCS is calculated per the algorithm specified in RFC 1662. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662#appendix-A

Can someone provide a way to calculate the crc16 in python.

here is the C# equivalent of what I am looking for.

```
public static class Crc16
{
    const ushort polynomial = 0x1021;

    static readonly ushort[] table = new ushort[256];

    public static ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = 0xffff;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ table[index]);
        }
        return (ushort)~crc;
    }

    static Crc16()
    {
        ushort value;
        ushort temp;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i)
        {
            value = 0;
            temp = i;
            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                }
                else
                {
                    value >>= 1;
                }
                temp >>= 1;
            }
            table[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't write code for you on stackoverflow, but if you already have working C# code why do you need python?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is, but these articles and modules may be helpful. [How do I create an FCS for PPP packets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4308606/9014308), [crc16 0.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/crc16/), [crcmod 1.7](https://pypi.org/project/crcmod/), [pycrc 0.9.2](https://pypi.org/project/pycrc/), [pythoncrc 1.21](https://pypi.org/project/pythoncrc/), [PyCRC-Hex 1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/PyCRC-Hex/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code:

```
import crcmod
f = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, initCrc=0, xorOut=0xffff)
print(hex(f(b'\x00\x03\x00\x02\x04\x00')))
```

The output is:

```
0x389b
```

Note that the CRC is then put in the packet in little-endian order.